# Adding tflite model to Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, bytebuffer, tflite

```
val model = Action.newInstance(this)

// Creates inputs for reference.

val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 30, 126), DataType.FLOAT32)
inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)

// Runs model inference and gets result.
val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer

// Releases model resources if no longer used.
model.close()
```

I want to pass a 2d array of dimension 30x126 of type float to my tflite model.
But how do I convert that to a bytebuffer.
Please help.